# Java linux how to move mouse cursor

Tags: java, linux, cursor, mouse, move

I am making a 3d multi-platform application and I would like to set mouse cursor always to middle. `robot.mouseMove(x,y)` works fine for Windows, but for Linux it really does not work.

I have a question if there is a method that would allow me to set mouse cursor at specific position for Windows, Linux, Mac.

*EDIT
This is what I got and works fine for Windows.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4887525192006201710L;
    private Frame self = this;
    private JPanel buffer = new JPanel(){
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    };
    private Robot robot;

    public Frame(String title){
        super(title);
        add(buffer);
        setBounds(0,0, 640,480);
        setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
                buffer.setBounds(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }

            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){}
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e){}
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            self.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(self, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Mouse moved");
        robot.mouseMove(getX()+getWidth()/2, getY()+getHeight()/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: I am running Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and robot.mouseMove(x,y) works fine for me.

Comment: Could it be due that I am using VirtualBox?

Comment: I don't know I am not using virtualbox. It couldn't hurt to add the virtualbox tag and add more details on your setup to the question or just try it on a normal linux setup.

Comment: Yes problem is in VirtualBox. I have just Installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04 (same as on VirtualBox) on my hard drive and robot works fine. I am not sure what information you mean by **tag** and **setup** detals.

Comment: OH! Well robots work in VirtualBox it changes "inside virtual machine mouse position"... but virtual box dont change position of the windows mouse cursor :(.

Comment: @WillShackleford Okay I found the way how to disable mouse integration in VirtualBox and everything works fine as I expected. Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*SOLUTION
Well, robot works fine. Problem was that there was no problem (Sorry). I thought robot is not working because VirtualBox was not moving my mouse to middle of the screen on Virtual Linux, but then I found out it is working but thanks to **Enabled Mouse Integration** I did not see original inside OS cursor.

For those what run VirtualBox and want to **Disable Mouse Integration** press key shortcut `hostkey(right ctrl) + I` and your cursor become native Virtual OS cursor.